# Rails - mean calculation of parent value based on children

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Book model `has_many` Ratings, which has `overall` attribute.

I want the `Book`'s `mean_rating` attribute to be updated every time a rating is added/destroyed.

What is the easiest way to do it?

Comment: Use an algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way (not thread-safe) is to use `after_create/after_destroy` callbacks in `Rating` model. See [documentation on model callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html)

If you need thread safe solution you will need to update `mean_rating` in delayed job or something. [This post](http://building.wanelo.com/2014/06/20/counter-cache-a-story-of-counting.html) might be a good start

Answer (score 2):

you can utilize the model lifecycle hooks, notable, `after_create`.

in your ratings model, you can write an after create hook that will update the mean_rating

```
#models/rating.rb

after_create :update_book_mean_rating

def update_book_mean_rating
  new_mean_rating = self.book.ratings.sum(:overall) / self.book.ratings.count
  self.book.update_attributes(mean_rating: new_mean_rating
end
```

you'll probably want to add validations / checks that makes sure a rating always has a book etc and doing something similar when destroying, but something like this should point you in the right direction